# Dynamic form loading

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, json

Hi I'm new to dynamic requests in ajax,jQuery,JSON,etc.
All I want to do is---

-User selects a city in the dropdown.

-Then,it should send request to controller via ajax,jquery etc.

-From controller,i'll make a query asking for locations corresponding to city in Location table

-And then,this will send response to view,in which the drop down list will be loaded using the former query in controller.

-All of this would be dynamic(self-explanatory)

Comment: What code do you have already?

Comment: what have you tried..??? there are already lots of same questions about how to make ajax call..how to pass data from controller to view using ajax and so on

Comment: can u please tell me source for documentation to read this!

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should paste the code whatever you tried unless no one form us can help you on this.

Or you can find these thing simply by using google also:

Try these links: http://goo.gl/pPWQ8

http://goo.gl/CrNwu

**EDIT:**

Check this JsBin http://jsbin.com/ozolem/4/watch